# Performance issues with applications deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

Recently we have migrated all our companies applications from Websphere to Tomcat application server. As part of this process we had performance testing done.

We found that couple of applications are having over 100% performance degradation in Tomcat. We increased the number of threads, we configured datasource settings to accommodate our test, we have also increased the read and write buffer sizes in the Tomcat server.

```
Application Background:

-> Spring Framework   
-> Hibernate   
-> Oracle 12c   
-> JSPs   
-> OpenJDK 8
```

We already checked the database and found no issues with performance in DB.
The CPU utilization while running the test is always less than `10%`.
Heap settings are `-xms = 1.5G to -xmx = 2G`, and it never utilizes more than `1.2G`.
We also have two nodes and HAProxy on top to balance the load. (We don't have a web server in place).

Despite our best efforts we couldn't pinpoint the issue that is causing the performance degradation. I am aware that this information isn't enough to provide a solution for our problem, however, any suggestion on how to proceed will be very helpful as we hit a dead-end and are unable to proceed.

Appreciate it if you can share any points that will be helpful in finding the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take Thread Dumps and analyze which part of application is having issues and start troubleshoot from there.

Follow this article for detailed explanation about Thread Dumps analysis - https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of possible reasons for the problem you've mentioned and there really isn't much data to work with. Regardless of that, as `kann` commented a good way to start would be gathering Thread Dumps of the java process.

I'd also question if you're running in the same servers or if it's newly setup servers and how they are looking (resource-wise). Is there any CPU/Memory/IO constraints during the test?

Regarding the Xmx it sounds like you're not passing the `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` flag to the JVM but I would advice you to look into it as it will make the JVM zero the heap memory on start-up instead of doing it in runtime (which can mean a performance hit).